# HTML: How to use iframe tag with CSS zoom / transform?

Tags: html, iframe

I'm trying to embed a web page (child web page - plain HTML/PHP) into another web page (parent web page - WordPress) by using HTML tag . On the parent web page, I only have 800 px width, but the child web page has approx. 1.600 px width, so I use CSS zoom / transform:

```html
<iframe style="zoom: 0.5; -moz-transform: scale(0.5); -moz-transform-origin: 0 0; -o-transform: scale(0.5); -o-transform-origin: 0 0; -webkit-transform: scale(0.5); -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;" src="https://www.example.com/example.html" width="800" height="1600">
</iframe>
```

Basically, it works, but the iframe fills only 50% of the available 800 px width = only 400 px width. Additionally, it cannot be centered, but is always aligned to the left.

I read and tried a lot, but nothing helps up to now. Hs anybody more ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok; I've found it.
You could use this code:

(Try it after clicking the “expand snippet” text, so that there is enough space for the snippet to show up properly)

```css
.parent {
 margin: 0 auto; 
 width: 90%; /*or 800px or as required*/
 overflow-y: visible;
 display: block;
}
```

```html
 <iframe class="parent" src="https://example.com/example.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">
```

Avoid using inline css, that detoriates SEO.

Comment: This makes the iframe 800px wide again, but its content it not zoomed to 50%, but stays at 100%, so that horizontal scrolling is necessary.

Comment: Add the scrolling="no" attribute to the iframe element.

Comment: Please check it out now.

Comment: With scrolling = "no", the scrolling bars disappear, but the content is still not zoomed to 50%, but stays at 100%, so only half of the total width/content is shown.

Comment: But my code snippet works nice enough... I've tried it myself. Maybe there is something in the page you're iframing. Can you please give the real domain name so that I can check the problem...

Comment: I'd prefer to send you the real domain name by private message, but how to do this on stackoverflow.com?

Comment: Check out my profile. I've given my work and personal email id.

Comment: Unfortunately, also the added padding and values in percent instead of px do not produce the desred behaviour, but the iframe still only covers only approx. 50% of the available width.

Comment: Have you removed the zoom?

Comment: Yes, but still the same problem.

Comment: But with example.com, my snippet works fine enough. Please email me  the real domain.

Comment: @dark_rider If you'd prefer not to tell the real domain name, it's really up to you. But one main question is whether you have put the meta viewport tag in the `head`? If not, you should put it without  any doubt. It reads like this: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`. Ever wondered how the desktop versions of websites fit on a mobile screen? It is due to this meta viewport.